# Macro that creates a list of all via another macro created functions

Tags: c++, macros

Here is what I need:

```
class Manager
{
    private:
        IParam *p1;
        IParam *p2;
        IParam *p3;

        std::vector<IParam*> allParams;

    public:

        void init() 
        {
            // init allParams list, simply calling all getter is enough here
            getP1();
            getP2();
            getP3();
        }

        IParam *getP1()
        {
            if (p1 == NULL)
            {
                p1 = new IParam("p1");
                allParams.push_back(p1);
            }
            return p1;
        }

        IParam *getP2()
        {
            if (p2 == NULL)
            {
                p2 = new IParam("p2");
                allParams.push_back(p2);
            }
            return p2;
        }

        IParam *getP3()
        {
            if (p3 == NULL)
            {
                p3 = new IParam("p3");
                allParams.push_back(p3);
            }
            return p3;
        }
}
```

My macro look look like following:

```
#define DEFINE_PARAM_CPP(NAME) \
        private: \
            IParam * NAME; \
        public: \
            IParam * get##NAME() \
            { \
                if (NAME == NULL) \
                { \
                    NAME = new IParam("NAME"); \
                    allParams.push_back(NAME); \
                } \
                return NAME; \
            }
```

**Question**

As you can see, I need to initialise a vector (`allParams`). The macro does not solve this problem yet (the `init` function is not created by the macro), any ideas how I could create the init function? Defining a static list and adding items to this list in the macro itself is no solution (check background info to find out why). I would need a macro that creates a list of all functions that have been created with the `DEFINE_PARAM_CPP` macro...

**Background**

My class is implementing an interface and it will be registered in another software's plugin API. This means, I can't create instances of `IParam` before all plugins are registered and the API allows me to create `IParam` objects (`IParam` objects are registered via another plugin). This means, I need to initialise my list in a lazy way like I currently do.

Comment: "any ideas how I could create the init function?" write it by typing the code yourself? To my experience, using macros only to save typing always ends in horror

Comment: this way it's easy to forget it. I don't want to do one thing (adding a parameter) and always have to add it at 2 places... I currently did copy the definitions into notepad++, apply a regex and copied the result back into my init function. I want to avoid this manual step and I want to avoid the danger of forgetting to register a parameter in the list

Comment: Why do you need `getP1()`, `getP2()`, etc? Why not having just one function `IParam* getP(int i)`? You would need no macro at all.

Comment: @user463035818 tell this to the google auto-test goup; if it wasn't so well supported in various IDE's I'd write my own that wasn't so macro abusive!

Comment: @UKMonkey imho if it is for a limited scope macros can be fine. I just wrote my own toy test framework based on macros. For tests I am fine with using arcane stuff as long as it doesnt leak into my actual code

Comment: Q1: Why do you need an `init` function? Lazy loading is already a requirement of your scenario, so why not take it to its conclusion: don't load a given `IParam` until it is needed?

Comment: Q2: It looks like `allParams` has a fixed length. (Why not use `std::array` instead?) Why don't you construct it to the required size, then loop over it, instead of listing each `getPN` individually? You could also get rid of the individual `pN` declarations.

Comment: @JaMiT because I have tools that need to know all available parameters, so I also have a getter for the `allParams` vector. And yes, an array would do it as well. And yes, you are right, if I can fill the array anyways, I can use it as well to avoid the need of declaring all the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way:

fields.h:

```
current_macro(p1)
current_macro(p2)
current_macro(p3)
```

manager.h

```
class Manager{
  private:
    #define current_macro //how you want define elements
    #include fields.h
    #undef current_macro
    std::vector<IParam*> allParams;
  public:
    #define current_macro //how you want your getter to look like
    #include fields.h
    #undef current_macro
    void init() 
    {
      #define current_macro //how you want your part of init look like
      #include fields.h
      #undef current_macro            
    }
}
```

Comment: omg, I'm doing this in multiple places already, did not see this solution to reuse a list...